# Get image and text side by side flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to get my AssetImage and Text side by side each other. To achieve that I used a row and it is being displayed like this:

```
Row(
                children: [
                                      Image.asset('assets/images/pfp.png',height: height*0.1,),
                  Column(children: [Text("we")],)

                ],
              )
```

[image]

I want the image to be displayed in this way:

[image]

I want the text to start from the top of the image. How do I achieve that? Below is the current code I have that displayed it as the first image:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Just add a cross axis alignment property to your Row widget

Set it to `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

You will have the expected result ✔️

Answer (score 0):

Use crossaxisalgnment

```
Row(
 crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children : [
     Image.asset(""),
     Text(""),
  ]
)
```